# redirecting to paypal's approval_url via javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, paypal

I need to use javascript to redirect to paypal's approval_url

if I do

```
window.location = "<%= approval_url %>";
```

I am getting to a page that says

```
This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow.
```

and the url is

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=xJniP0ittD1dtW_QGQXqLx91Byimw8A3ZvU71TCcY6Ktm-hyIhp2dpF7SoboFa&dispatch=50a222a57ty771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081982546798d23b9808f2b0faaf533a5dbe5
```

However, if I manually take the approval_url and paste it in the browser it reaches the page successfully.

What is the difference here?

Comment: where are you passing return url, as we have to provide that in paypal,

Comment: i pass that in the payment creation. Once paypal responds I need to redirect the use to the approval_url, where the user logs in paypal and pays.

Answer (score 0):

this is odd..

seems paypal doesn't like `&amp;` in the url.. if I do `raw approval_url` it behaves normally..